# How do I optimize an algorithm to decompose a number as the sum of two squares?

Tags: python, python-3.x, math, optimization

I have a simple math algo. All it does is it takes an input and finds i,j such that i^2 + j^2 = input with the restriction that j >= i (so that it doesn't print it's counterpart e.g., 2^2 + 3^2 == 3^2 + 2^2 but I only need the latter as j >= i)

For my code, I did the following: I have 2 for loops, first loop for i and second loop for j. Takes both i and j values and test if i^2 + j^2 == input and if j >= i. if yes, print it and update count.

The problem is, with large sums of values, it takes a very long time as it loops twice from 1 to 2000 and then 1 to 2000 again.

```
def some_mathfn(n):
    count = 0
    for i in range(1,n+1):
        for j in range(1,n+1):
            if(i**2 + j**2 == n and j >= i):
                g = print(i, '^2 + ', j,'^2')
                count += 1
    return count

some_mathfn(2001)
```

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a good platform for brainstorming an algorithm. At the very least, come up with a better title to your question.

Comment: for j in range(i+1, n+1) would cut out a reasonable proportion of the loop, and remove second part of if statement as now redundant.

Comment: @MartijnPieters would you know what websites are suitable more problems like this?

Comment: IMHO it is interesting; agree with Lewis Fogden

Comment: @misheekoh: Perhaps chat.stackoverflow.com?

Comment: although your algorithm doesn't state this, sometimes n is itself a square number, so if you reduced your search space from all numbers to just the squares, this could conceivably lower the computational burden; how to do this easily isn't clear, unless you made an enumerated array with the square numbers... of course you may wish to consider a  more general case , e.g. 7*7 + 1*1 = 50, where 50 isn't a "perfect square", then this wouldn't help....

Comment: Try CodeReview.StackExchange.com or Math.StackExchange.com.  Also check out [Fermat's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_theorem_on_sums_of_two_squares) and [Pell's equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pell%27s_equation) for general work on the topic.

Comment: Personally I think this is okay here. It's a specific enough question, it's basically about finding a faster algorithm... The [ask] page does specifically say "Ask about... [...] software algorithms." There are plenty of optimization questions that are massively vague etc - but this seems okay.

Comment: The best way to implement this is by factorising n over the Gaussian integers (straightforward from the prime factorisation) and then you can go from that to your answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You've got an O(n<sup>2</sup>) algorithm for no obvious reason. It's easy to make this O(n<sup>1/2</sup>)...

- Loop from 1 to the square root of `n/2` (for variable `i`) - because when `i` is greater than `sqrt(n/2)` then `i*i + j*j` will be greater than `n` for any `j` greater than `i`.

  - (Only to the square root of `n`, because
- Subtract the square of `i`
- Take the square root of the result, and find the nearest integer - call that `j`
- Check whether the condition you're interested in holds

The last two steps are effectively just checking that the square root of `n - i*i` is actually an integer, but in some cases (for very large values of n) finding the nearest integer and then checking the condition could be a more reliable approach, in order to avoid floating point limitations causing issues, where the nearest-representable double to the theoretical result could be an integer, despite that actual result not being an integer. This would only happen for really large values of n, but...

Comment: @JonSkeet the thing is that range() won't take float!!

Comment: @misheekoh: So round down to the nearest integer. You only care about integer values, after all...